# capturing right-click+left-click with autohotkey; unexpected behaviour

Tags: windows, mouse, autohotkey

I want to capture the key event "right mouse button pressed, then left mouse button pressed". No problem in autohotkey. However I am having trouble with still allowing the right-mouse key to work alone.

1) this works:

```
RButton & LButton::
    Send X
Return
```

works as expected:

- If I press right mouse button, then left mouse button, "X" is sent to the active window
- right-click event is captured by Authotkey: **no** context menu appears when I press the right mouse button alone. This is the intended outcome

---

2) this works

```
~RButton & LButton::
    Send Y
Return
```

works as expected:

- If I press right mouse button, then left mouse button, "Y" is sent to the active window
- right-click event is not captured by Authotkey: context menu **does** appear when I press the right mouse button alone or together with the left button. This is the intended outcome

---

3) Now I want to do different things depending on the active window.

this does not work *(careful: this will disable righ-click in every application)*

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")

RButton & LButton::
    Send X
Return


#If !WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
~RButton & LButton::
    Send Y
Return
```

does not work as expected:

- in Firefox left-right sends X, in other applications left-right sends Y
- however, right-click is disabled in **every** application

What am I doing wrong here?

---

edit:

the goal is this: I want a global hotkey on Right+left-click with `RButton & LButton` . In specific applications that I have tested for compatibility, I want right+left click to suppress sending right-click, and then send right-click manually using autohotkey. However, since some applications might have trouble processing mouseevents sent by autohotkey, in all untested applications I want to use `~RButton & LButton` with the ~ to pass throught right-click events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one that supports right click dragging!

```
Hotkey, LButton, off

#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
RButton & LButton::
    Send X
Return

RButton::return

#IfWinNotActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
~$RButton::
Hotkey, LButton, on
while GetKeyState("RButton", "P") {
    continue
    }
Hotkey, LButton, off
Return

LButton::Send Y
Return
```

It handles `RButton` manually. When `RButton` is pressed, it enables the `LButton` hotkey and waits for `RButton` to be released before deactivating it. The `RButton` hotkey uses `~`, which passes the click through normally.

`LButton` is disabled at the start by the line at the top.

Another way would have been to send `{RButton Down}` at the start of the hotkey and `{RButton Up}` at the end.

In response to your edit, the only programs that reject Autohotkey's sent events should be those that rely on low level hooks... The real trouble with the method down at the bottom is it only sends a single click, not processing holding the button. This method, and sending down and up separately, should both do that properly.

The bug with active window described at the bottom of this answer still exists, but that's a problem with the `#IfWin[Not]Active`.

---

#### Old stuff

See the [documentation on the ampersand](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) (emphasis mine):

> You can define a custom combination of two keys (except joystick buttons) by using " & " between them. In the below example, you would hold down Numpad0 then press the second key to trigger the hotkey:
>
> ```
> Numpad0 & Numpad1::MsgBox You pressed Numpad1 while holding down Numpad0.
> Numpad0 & Numpad2::Run Notepad
> ```
>
> **In the above example, Numpad0 becomes a prefix key; but this also causes Numpad0 to lose its original/native function when it is pressed by itself.** To avoid this, a script may configure Numpad0 to perform a new action such as one of the following:
>
> ```
> Numpad0::WinMaximize A   ; Maximize the active/foreground window.
> Numpad0::Send {Numpad0}  ; Make the release of Numpad0 produce a Numpad0 keystroke. See comment below.
> ```
>
> The presence of one of the above hotkeys causes the release of Numpad0 to perform the indicated action, but only if you did not press any other keys while Numpad0 was being held down.

So, following that example:

```
#If WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")

RButton & LButton::
    Send X
Return

RButton::return

#If !WinActive("ahk_class MozillaWindowClass")
RButton & LButton::
    Send Y
Return

RButton::Send {RButton}
```

Note `RButton` requires a variant that does nothing in `WinActive`, at least with my testing (see below): `RButton::return`

---

Since I'm using Autohotkey standard, not Autohotkey_L, I don't have `#If` and the above was untested. The following I *did* test, and it works.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
RButton & LButton::
    Send X
Return

RButton::return


#IfWinNotActive ahk_class MozillaWindowClass
RButton & LButton::
    Send Y
Return

RButton::Send {RButton}
```

An interesting bug I've noticed is the second (NotActive) variant applies occasionally to Firefox:

1. Another window is active
2. `RButton` *down* is sent
3. Firefox is not active, so the second variant is processed
4. <delay> (`RButton` is held down, though the delay could be imperceptible, in the order of milliseconds, to infinite)
5. Firefox becomes active
6. <delay> (still held down)
7. `RButton` *up* is sent, which sends `RButton` as per the documentation. Because Firefox became active in the delay between the active window check and when `RButton` is sent, `RButton` is sent to Firefox.

This happens when both Firefox and another window are visible, and the other window is the active one at the time of the click.

I've tried to fix this bug by adding an extra `IfWinNotActive` check within the `RButton` hotkey, but it did not seem to work.

Comment: Thanks, I did not think of trying `RButton::Send {RButton}`! however, I am a bit concerned this might lead to problems later in some applications that use right-drag or use a method to proccess mouse events incomatible with AHK's send command. The nice thing about ~RButton & LButton (in the second working variant from the question) is that it does not modify the right-click event at all, so those applications will be able to process right-clicks undisturbed, and only the right+left click is modified.

Comment: The problem is, in this scenario the default of hotkey activation on keydown has been changed to keyup. I don't see any option to change this. It's also possible (I guess) `RButton` only, without the ` & LButton`, and use a `while` loop that checks the state of `RButton` within. If you're happy with this suggestion, and any issues with it you can think of, let me know and I'll write it up.

Comment: Well, I am not to keen on running a script that modifies right-click globally. That seems like the sort of thing I'll forget and wonder in 3 months why a particular application does not react to right-click. I suppose I could use a whitelist of applications, since I probably won't need my right+left click script in every app. I am not sure whether a while loop would work better, you'd still have to capture right-click globally to avoid sending it to specific applications, right?

Comment: The one I've just added at the top of the answer seems to work everything I threw at it. It still has to set up the `RButton` variant on Firefox to block it, and passes it through (`~`) on all other programs.

Comment: Thanks, looks very nice so far, will test it!