# switch tabs quickly with scroll wheel

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I'm wondering if it's possible to quickly switch editor tabs in Visual Studio 2013 in a similar fashion to Sublime Text on Windows (hold right click and scroll).

That is, is it possible to use mouse input in keyboard shortcuts? I have searched for an extension that will allow this, but without luck,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible as a general solution with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), a keyboard and mouse shortcut program for Windows, although it's going to take some work to make it happen without breaking Right Click on your entire system.

```
This is an example script which will do the normal tab switching, but WILL BREAK RIGHT CLICK

RButton & WheelUp::Send {CTRL DOWN}{SHIFT DOWN}{TAB}{SHIFT UP}{CTRL UP}
RButton & WheelDown::Send {CTRL DOWN}{TAB}{CTRL UP}
```

I'm not sure if Ctrl-TAB works in Visual Studio, but if you can find a key combination to do it, you can automate that with AutoHotkey.

Here is a discussion about capturing mouse clicks for a specific application, without breaking right click for the entire system, that you could probably build from: [capturing right-click+left-click with autohotkey; unexpected behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317568/capturing-right-clickleft-click-with-autohotkey-unexpected-behaviour)

Comment: Did not think of AHK, that's a very interesting possibility. Not sure if I'll have time to make it work (or if the productivity boost will be worth the effort), but I'll give it a shot when I have some time